# Web browser control not showing images in Windows XP

Tags: c#, winforms

I've added an **webbrowser** to my window form. It shows all images properly in **Windows 10** But when I run my application at **Windows XP** it did not shows images. Whole Content is very well except images.

Comment: Which .Net Framework are you using?

Comment: I am using .Net FrameWork 4 so my application support on all previous version windows.

Comment: On one special site? does it work with IE? Because the Webbrowser uses the same Core as IE! Have you tried it in VisualStudio with WinXP? Btw XP is not longer supported from Windows so it is a huge security issue!

Comment: But some sectors are using windows XP. The framework is supportive all over. If web browser control displaying me the content it must display images  too.

Comment: Why dont you use .NET WebKit control instead of an obsolete web browser?

Comment: the problem is possibly that the webbrowser on XP will use the IE6,7 or 8 rendering engine (depending on what is installed). Like Sv said above, using a plugin based on another rendering engine might be more reliable.

Comment: Not showing images on a web page is a standard option, still today, tended to be used more often on old slow machines.  Affects WebBrowser as well.  Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced to configure.

Comment: Sir, Show images in Advanced Tab is already ticked. Any other option which should i suppose to tick??

Comment: And i have also tried embedding google chrome to my project but the CefSharp supports framework 4.5.2 whether am using framework 4. If am using higher version then this and install my application on XP it gives error of null win32

Comment: My Windows XP already have installed IE 8. As we know Windows  XP not support after IE8 version.